# Multiple Publish inside a transactionScope fails

Tags: oracle, nservicebus, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I modeled an integration architecture between different subsystems. All notification from a subsystem are sent to the subscribed subsystems using the primitive `Publish`. These notifications are sent in a `for` loop inside an `Handler` method, so they are all in the same `TransactionScope`. I did a simple example to explain this: A client send a message to a server that send a variable number of messages using the primitive `Publish`. This is the server handler:

```
public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < message.numberOfNotifications; i++)
        {
            Bus.Publish<NotificationMessage>(m =>
            {
                m.myPersonalCount= i;
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

What I'm looking and I can't figure out is that when I set `i` to 30 or less everything is OK. From 31 or more I get this error message:

```
could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.SubscriberEndpoint as y0_ FROM "Subscription" this_ WHERE this_.MessageType in (?) ]
```

And looking in the inner exception I get `Unable to enlist in a distributed transaction`.

I tried the same using the primitive `Send` but everything was(tried with 10k messages), so this is a problem pertinent only to the `Publish` directive.

I use Oracle 10g for dbms and Oracle 11g for client.

If the endpoint is not transactional I don't have any problem and so the problem seems to concern only with the TransactionScope.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What version of NServiceBus are you using?

Comment: @ChrisBednarski I use versione 2.0.1329.2, i know it's a very old version..

Comment: I'd suggest moving to a new version of NSB - similar to answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12478656/136720

Comment: Have you turned on the Oracle MTS tracing in the registry?  Also, there is another resource pool for MTS that may be capping you.

Comment: Yes i turned it on but looks ok, what's the other resource pool you are talking about? how can i monitor it?

Comment: There is a pool for connections and a pool for MTS transactions.  Both caps can be set in the registry.  Refer to the Oracle MTS docs for how to turn on tracing in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Oracle expert by any stretch of the imagination. I probably wouldn't even qualify as novice.

However, I know that NServiceBus queries the subscription storage for every single publish, in case there are changes to subscriptions between publishes.

Is it possible that the Oracle client has some sort of limitation to how many queries can enlist in a distributed transaction? Perhaps as a way to prevent N+1 types of performance problems?

That said, it seems very odd that you would want to publish more than 30 of the same type of event. I wonder what your business use case is. Events are generally supposed to announce that something irrevocable has happened. Why would there be 30 things that have happened?

If the business case is solid, it might be a good idea to implement your own subscription storage engine that uses some limited caching (5 seconds even) so that you aren't returning to querying the database on every single publish.

Comment: I have single events that can set off up to 20k notification messages. I did it becouse my system is expected to be very scalable and sending all these small messages instead of one with a lot of data in my opinion is more suitable to my performance constraints. What do you think about? However if the endpoint is not transactional i don't have any problem and so the problem seems to be in the TransactionScope context..